# Webpack 4 import scss through alias

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

So I have a node script running webpacking alot of folders for different installations on our server,

```
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                minimize: true,
                alias: {
                  './assets/images': imagesPath,
                  './bootstrap/config': resolve(`/External_Assets/LocalFiles/${item.id}/_config.scss`)
                }
              }
            },
```

item.id is just the path to the folder that contains a config file for scss variables. When we build the project locally we had just one config file, referenced like this

`@import './bootstrap/config';`

Which is just like the path referenced in the alias, why is this not working? It still goes and grabs the variables from the old folder. I have not found any other references to that file.

Answer (score 3):

## Edit 1

Made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/eldar-gamisoniya/ab53a7ee0dda77d6c1a1e2ac540baab5) as a working example.

Main points:

- Move alias to resolve. As you are using `_config.scss` file i guess there's `sass-loader` running before `css-loader` and it wouldn't work because there are no aliases at that point of time.
- i couldn't make alias work for specific .scss file, though you can just point to the folder instead - `` bootstrap': resolve(`/External_Assets/LocalFiles/${item.id}`) ``
- .scss files have special syntax for loading non-relative paths (should start with ~). I.e. instead of `@import 'bootstrap/config';` should be `@import '~bootstrap/config`

Config:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'assets/images': imagesPath, 
      'bootstrap': resolve(`/External_Assets/LocalFiles/${item.id}`)
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...  
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              minimize: true,
            }
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Reference in `.scss` file:

```
@import "~bootstrap/config";
```

## Old answer

`css-loader`'s alias works the same as webpack's [resolve.alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) option. According to the docs aliases work only for [module paths](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#module-paths).In your case relative paths specified.

To make it work, you can use the following options in your loader config:

```
alias: {
    'assets/images': imagesPath,
    'bootstrap/config': resolve(`/External_Assets/LocalFiles/${item.id}/_config.scss`)
    }
```

And then change import to
    `@import 'bootstrap/config';`

Comment: Hi, thank you for explaining, however, that did not solve the issue.